# Javascript const is changeable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to delete max value from arMin and min value from arMax, but arr (is a const!) changes too! I don't know why. I am using Google Chrome version 65.0.3325.181.
'arr' is only one time declared and it shouldn't do nothing with that. I can't understand that. Tried with delete, but it's turning numbers into 'empty', but works the same and changes const too!
It's my first post, so  if I do something wrong please forgive me.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arMin = arr;
let arMax = arr;
let min = arMin.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, arMin));
let max = arMax.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, arMax));

arMin.splice(max, 1);
arMax.splice(min, 1);

console.log(arMin); // [2,3,4]
console.log(arMax); // [2,3,4]
console.log(arr); // [2,3,4]
```

Comment: I think your thinking of immutable rather than changeable?

Comment: Have you searched? This is well documented.

Comment: Use `arr.slice()` to make a copy of an array, use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to make an immutable array.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `arr` is a reference to an array.

You cannot change that. It will *always* be a reference to that array.

Arrays are mutable though, so you can change values in the array. `const` won't prevent that.

If you want `arMin` and `arMax` to be different arrays, then you need to make a copy of the array and not just copy the value of `arr` (which is a reference to that array).

Answer (score 0):

`const` makes the reference constant, not the value.

You can't make `arr` point to something else, but you can change its values.

Note: other languages, [Dart comes to mind](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html?m=1), have the ability of specifying constant values. That's not the case of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To complete previous answer, to make an exact copy of array instead of copying reference, you should do something like this :

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arMin = [...arr]; // We use spread operator to create new array from original one.
let arMax = [...arr];
let min = arMin.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, arMin));
let max = arMax.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, arMax));

arMin.splice(max, 1);
arMax.splice(min, 1);

console.log(arMin); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(arMax); // [2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

--- EDIT 1 ---
*i use TypeScript synthax to illustrate type*

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.push(6); // Is allow.

const object: {id: number, title: string} = {id: 1, title: 'Yanis'};
object.id = 2; // Is allow.

const myString: string = 'yanis';
myString = 'Jackob'; // Not allow.
```

Comment: Please refer to _which_ answer. "Previous answer" means near nothing.

Comment: Thank You for that answer. So const keeps only the type of a variable but not a value?

Comment: On case of complexe type such as Array or object, yes. But for basic type like string, integer, no. You can't override this basic type. But you can update Array or object. I have update my answer to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an array const then you can not change the reference

```
const arr = [1,2,3]
arr = [4,5,6] \\ Throws errors; You can not change const reference
arr[1] = 6; \\ Works fine. You are not changing the const reference. You are just mutating the array.
const x = 5; \\ Here constant  is the value
x = x + 1; \\ Error. You can not change the constant value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a constant, you can't reassign its value, in this case, it contains the reference to the array.

But the array itself is not immutable.

An example would be:

```
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

arr = 'foo' // You cannot do that

arr.push(6) // That works fine. result: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```